# Global statement seems not to work with scripts on ipython3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, global

I have the following script

*test.py*:

```
a=1

def f() :
    global a
    a=2
```

When I run this script in *ipython3* I get the following results:

```
In [1]: a
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3f786850e387> in <module>
----> 1 a

NameError: name 'a' is not defined

In [2]: run test

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: f()

In [5]: a
Out[5]: 1
```

Since I declare `a` as a global variable, why does its value not change to 2 when I run the function `f()`?

Comment: Global means belonging to the namespace of the module (in this case `test`). If you declare a variable in another namespace (e.g. your interpreter session), it's a different variable.

Comment: If it is like you say, @khelwood, why can I get the value of ```a``` as being 1?

Comment: If you imported the test module it would be available as `test.a`. I don't use ipython so I don't know what you're doing there.

Comment: Yeah... I know how it would behave if I import it as a module. But I am doing something else. And I am using ipython3, as I stated in my question.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I suspect that must be something like you said. However what puzzles me is that the variable ```a``` is accessible from the ipython3 command line, returning the value 1. And since it is declared global inside ```f()``` its values should have changed to 2. Why does it didnt?

Comment: @MisterMiyage, no, I didn't define it somewhere else before. As you can see in my question, those are the first lines of my ipython3 section. I suggest you try running it.

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer that the variable ```a``` was not available before I run the script.

Comment: @bmello Oh my, thanks for updating the question. I hope some of the people that downvoted see their misconception as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: The namespace of the module which is `run` is *copied* to the IPython namespace, not *shared*. By the time `f()` is run, the namespaces are not longer synchronised.

---

When IPython executes a module via `run`, it does so in a new namespace; after completion the elements of this namespace are copied to the main IPython namespace.

> #### [Built-in magic commands `%run`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run)
>
> [...]
> The file is executed in a namespace initially consisting only of
> `__name__=='__main__'` and sys.argv constructed as indicated. It
> thus sees its environment as if it were being run as a stand-alone
> program (except for sharing global objects such as previously imported
> modules). **But after execution, the IPython interactive namespace gets
> updated with all variables defined in the program** (except for **name**
> and sys.argv). This allows for very convenient loading of code for
> interactive work, while giving each program a 'clean sheet' to run in.
> [...]

During execution of the program, `a=1` and `def f(): ...` are executed. As a result, both `a=1` and `f` are copied back to the main namespace.

Notable, `f` is not called before completion. When manually invoking `f()`, its global namespace is still the one in which `test` was executed; only the `test` namespace is modified by `f()`.

Comment: Thanks. But things are still confusing. As you can see below, I cannot reach variable ```a``` in the ```test``` namespace. Furthermore, if I define the same function ```f()``` in the command line, it does change the variable ```a```. Therefore, it seems that when the function ```f()``` is copied from the script, it does not consider the main namespace in its global statement.

Comment: In [6]: test.a
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a8884f795355> in <module>
----> 1 test.a

NameError: name 'test' is not defined

In [7]: def f() :
   ...:     global a
   ...:     a=2
   ...: 

In [8]: a
Out[8]: 1

In [9]: f()

In [10]: a
Out[10]: 2

In [11]:

Comment: If you define *another* ``f`` inside the main namespace, that ``f``'s global will be the main namespace. The ``f`` inside test has been defined inside the test namespace, and will always see this as its global namespace. When copying ``f`` from ``test``, the function is not *redefined*; only its variable (name) is copied. This is the same as if you would import it.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. Do you know if it is possible to access the variable ```a``` from the namespace test from the ipython3 command line? How?

Comment: You can access ``f.__globals__`` for the global namespace of ``test``. It does not seem as if the module itself is accessible.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [2]: run test.py
In [3]: a
Out[3]: 1
In [4]: f()
In [5]: a
Out[5]: 1
```

With the '-i' argument:

```
In [6]: run -i test.py
In [7]: a
Out[7]: 1
In [8]: f()
In [9]: a
Out[9]: 2
```

from `run?`:

```
-i
  run the file in IPython's namespace instead of an empty one. This
  is useful if you are experimenting with code written in a text editor
  which depends on variables defined interactively.
```

Answer (score 0):

As @MisterMiyagi pointed out, the explanation is that the variables, functions, and other objects are copied at the end of the `run` command. Therefore, the variable `a` in the `test` namespace is not the same as the variable `a` in the `main` namespace, although they point to the same object. It is an immutable variable in the question's example; therefore, any change to it done inside the function results in the variable on the `test` namespace pointing to a new object.

However, if the variable is mutable and if this object changes but the variable is not redefined inside the function, its new value will be the same for both variables `a`:

*test.py*:

```
a=[1,2,3]

def f() :
    global a
    a+=[1]
```

ipython3 section:

```
In [1]: run test

In [2]: a
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3]

In [3]: f()

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 1]
```

If I replace `a+=[1]` by `a=a+[1]` in the function definition, which creates a new object `a+[1]` instead of updating the object pointed by `a`, the result is

```
In [4]: a
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3]
```

since, after running `f()`, the variable `a` from the `test` namespace will point to a new object, not changing the previously pointed object.